# Save response from axios GET call to Firebase database in JavaScript part of a Firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Have written a function which works fine apart from the following:

- Desired behavior: Is to save the `response.data` received from the axios GET call back to Firebase database
- Specific problem: The data is not being saved to Firebase and
  function terminates with a status code: 500 error
- Code: The following    code is a snippet of the function, the line
  which is not working is the .update(response.data)

Console outputting the status code:500 and `k, posID, name` values:

[image]

Code *(edit: to  include entire function as per comments provided)*:

```
    exports.doshiiMenuUpdatedWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  // Forbidding PUT requests.
  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }

  cors(req, res, () => {

    let verify = req.query.verify;
    let locationId = req.body.data.locationId
    let posId = req.body.data.posId
    let type = req.body.data.type
    let uri = req.body.data.uri
    let itemUri = req.body.data.itemUri

    var token = jwttoken();

    const options = {
        headers: {'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
      };


    switch (type) {

    case 'products':
        console.log('Event - specific menu item updated');
        console.log('jwt: ', token);


        axios.get(itemUri, options)
          .then(response => {

            console.log('response status: ', response.status);
            console.log('response statusText: ', response.statusText);

            return admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/products`)
                 .once('value').then((snapshot) => {

                  var products = snapshot.val();
                  var keys = Object.keys(products);

                  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){

                    var k = keys[i];
                    var name = products[k].name;
                    var posID = products[k].posId;

                    if (posID === posId){

                      console.log(k, posID, name); 
                      admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/products/${key}/`).update(response.data);

                    }//end if

                  }//end for

                  return snapshot
                });

          })
          .then(response => {
                    return res.status(200).send(type)
            })
          .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).send({error: err})
          })//end axios


        break;
    case 'options':
        console.log('Event - specific menu option updated');
        console.log('jwt: ', token);
        break;
    case 'surcounts':
        console.log('Event - specific menu surcount updated');
        console.log('jwt: ', token);


        break;
    default:
        console.log('Event - entire menu  updated');
        console.log('jwt: ', token);

        axios.get(uri, options)
          .then(response => {

            console.log('response status: ', response.status);
            console.log('response statusText: ', response.statusText);

            return admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/`).set(response.data)
          })
          .then(response => {
                    return res.status(200).send(type)
            })
          .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).send({error: err})
          })//end axios


    }//end switch



  })//end cors

});
```

Comment: There's too little code here to tell what's going on.  Please edit the question to show the minimal complete Cloud Function deployment that fails in the way you're describing.  I will point out that you're not handling errors at all from the call to update().  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have updated the question to include the entire function. Let me point out that the `.set()` call within the `default` section of the `switch` statement works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring the promise returned from the call to `update()`.  HTTP functions must only send a response after **all** the async work is complete.  If any operation is unfinished at the time of the response, it could be dropped complete, as Cloud Functions will clean up and move on to the next request without waiting.

You should instead return the value of that promise so that it can be propagated along the chain.  (Or better, use JavaScript async/await syntax to avoid all the nested callbacks, which are difficult to track.)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, im still really new to JS so just trying to figure the changes I need to make to the code :/